# Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas) quality

Tags: html2canvas

When I use Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG, the quality is bad.

```
 html2canvas($("#surface"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
```

before

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: Your question is how do I prevent a circle from distorting when saving using saveAsPNG which is part of the html2canvas library? http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/   Could this be a bug with the library referenced?  Have you tried just saving the circle by itself.  Does it still distort?

Comment: this problem isn't just with saveAsPNG, similar with saveAsJPEG and when i try the circle i have this :